# Is it possible to map ‘Ctrl+CapsLock’ to escape key in VSCode Vim?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, vim, visual-studio-code

I’m using a <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key as a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and an <kbd>Esc</kbd> key using below command

```
remapCapsLockToControl() {
    xmodmap -e 'keycode 66 = Control_L'
    xmodmap -e 'clear Lock'
    xmodmap -e 'add Control = Control_L'
    echo "remapCapsLockToControl"
}

remapControlToEsc() {
    xcape -e "Control_L=Escape"
    echo "remapControlToEsc"
}
```

I can use a <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key as an <kbd>Esc</kbd> key in Vim (Ubuntu 18) with these settings. But I can’t use a <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key as an <kbd>Escape</kbd> key in VSCode vim mode. VSCode displays a message below when pressing a <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key.

> (Ctrl+CapsLock) was pressed. Waiting for second key …

I can’t input the `Ctrl+CapsLock` key to `extension.vim_escape` of “Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcut”. A key input window is closed when press a <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key.

Answer (score 8):

I found a solution to map `Ctrl+CapsLock` to `vim_escape` key.

1. Enter “Preferences: Open Keyboard Shortcut” Menu (using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>)
2. Click a `extension.vim_escape` item.
3. Hold the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key for 3+ seconds.
   [image: dialog box for extension.vim_escape key]
4. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

[image: display current extension.vim_escape shortkey]

Comment: Excellent self-answered question!

Comment: It worked like a charm

Comment: I found two notes: 1) You can right click and "Add Keybinding" to keep the original as an option for `vim_escape`. 2) The keybinding I am trying to add is CapsLock+[ (I have caps lock mapped as control via xmodmap but VS Code seems to see through this somehow...) and holding the key combination down for a while does nothing. However, very quickly pressing CapsLock+[+Enter does the trick!

Answer (score 1):

This might not count as an answer, but the reason that VSCode is picking up the ctrl is because of the keyboard.dispatch setting, this answer has more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48143069/vscode-remap-capslock

Comment: Nothing wrong with linking an answer from another Stack Exchange site, but you should quote pertinent text from [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49219351/117259) here as well so this answer is complete. Otherwise, it’s just a link-only answer.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1102485)